# How to override action Email SalesOrder in SO30100 Screen

Tags: email, cloud, erp, acumatica

I try to customize action email in Salesorder screen, I use this code but it does not work. Could you give me some suggest about my code and customize send notification in Acumatica. I am using Acumatica 4.2.
Thank you in advance.

```
    public CRActivityList<SOOrder>    Activity;

    public PXAction<SOOrder> notification;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Notifications", Visible = false)]
    [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntryF)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable Notification(PXAdapter adapter,
        [PXString] string notificationCD
        )
    {
        foreach (SOOrder order in adapter.Get<SOOrder>())
        {
            if (order.OrderType == "CM")
            {
                ///my function
                EmailNotification.Send_AtNPP(order, "SO301000", "SENDRETURNSO", "[[NoiDung]]", createEmailContent(order));
            }
            yield return order;
        }
        yield return adapter.Get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you receive?
Have you tried removing the final yield?  Last line can be

```
return adapter.Get();
```

Comment: I have remove that and it cannot get into when I debug

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would need the yield return order, 
just do as suggested and return the adapter.

```
foreach (SOOrder order in adapter.Get<SOOrder>())
{
   if (order.OrderType == "CM")
    {
    ///my function
      EmailNotification.Send_AtNPP(order, "SO301000", "SENDRETURNSO", "[[NoiDung]]", createEmailContent(order));
   }
   //yield return order;
}
return adapter.Get();
```